# Splitting a row into multiple columns

Tags: tables, math-mode, graphics

I am trying to create a matrix illustration for a paper, however, I am running into an issue with splitting a row into multiple columns.

My code is as follows:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{align} \label{eq:2}
    \phi = &
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
        states & 1 2 3 4 5 0 \\
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        IM \\
        SA \\
        NB \\
        B  \\
        FD \\
        D  \\
    \end{tabular} &
    \left(
    \begin{tabular}{*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}}}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & $\phi_{NB}$ & 0 & $1-\phi_{NB}$ & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & $\phi_{B}$ & $1-\phi_{B}$ & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \right)
    \end{tabular}
\end{align} 
\end{center}
```

This produces

[image]

How do I split 1 2 3 4 5 0 into 6 cells so that they align with the columns in the parentheses? Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[columns-width=auto,first-row,first-col]%{c c c c c c c}
        states & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 \\
        IM & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        SA & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        \phi NB & 0 & 0 & \phi_{NB} & 0 & 1-\phi_{NB} & 0 \\
        B  & 0 & 0 & 0 & \phi_{B} & 1-\phi_{B} & 0 \\
        FD & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        D  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image]